# ngx-charts: Automatic sizing does not work correctly in CSS grid or Flexbox

Tags: ngx-charts

When an array of charts are placed in a grid, each subsequent column in the row produces a chart that is larger than the one that precedes it.

It seems that, unless you explicitly specify hard-coded sizes, the chart sizing logic does not work well inside of a grid or flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles across this issue in the future, I spent alot of time trying to figure this out until I tried doing something like below:

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d
            [scheme]="colorScheme"
            [results]="data"
            [xAxis]="true"
            [yAxis]="true"
            [legend]="true"
            [legendPosition]="legendPosition"
            [showXAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel === undefined"
            [showYAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel === undefined"
            [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel ?? ''"
            [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel ?? ''">
        </ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d>
        <div *ngIf="legendBelow" class="bottom-padding"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.inner-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This seems to work perfectly so far.